# Is TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning a right option for a long-time and peridiocally running job when using Task.Factory.StartNew method?

Tags: c#, .net, task, threadpool

Just like the code shown below:

```cs
Task.Factory.StartNew(async() =>
{
     while (true)
     {
         await Task.Delay(5 * 60 * 1000); // execute per 5 minutes
         // do somework
     }
}, TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach | TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```

Where `TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach` flag is default option for `Task.Factory.StartNew` method.

edit:

Thanks for the answers!

1、I just want to know is `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` a right option for a long-time and peridiocally running job when using `Task.Factory.StartNew` method;

2、No need for a better solution like `Timer` or `Quartz`, although they are good at the job ^_^.

Comment: Please explain to use what you think `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` does.

Comment: In short though - yes, you should use it here (since it is running for 5+ minutes).

Comment: Its debatable whether this should just be a threaded timer

Comment: From my experience, `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunnin` is very rarely useful. It's currently implemented so that it creates a dedicated thread behind the scene, instead of using thread pool. Most likely, there is a better way to achieve what you're after, but you'd need to tell us more.

Comment: Using a thread that sleeps for a long time is a waste of a thread

Comment: @noseratio I need a dedicated thread executes a work periodically very like what `System.Threading.Timer` do.

Comment: So why dont you want to use a timer?

Comment: Unless you need thread affinity, Task.Delay is usually a better option, see the Theodor's answers.

Comment: `LongRunning` doesn't make sense when used with an `async` delegate. [`StartNew` is a low-level method with dangerous default parameter values](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html).

Answer (score 1):

Normally there is no need to have a blocked thread doing nothing most of the time. Instead you should consider making the processing asynchronous, using `Task.Run` and `await Task.Delay`. This way you'll use a thread-pool thread only for the duration of the actual processing. The thread will not be the same thread every time, but this should not be a problem.

```
var worker = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    while (true)
    {
        await Task.Delay(5 * 60 * 1000); // execute per 5 minutes
                                         // do somework
    }
});
```

Comment: @MickyD [`ConfigureAwait(false)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.configureawait) makes no difference in this case, because the processing is started in a thread-pool thread, without synchronization context. You can check yourself that `SynchronizationContext.Current` is always `null` inside the body of the asynchronous delegate. I just confirmed it by running this code in the button click handler of a Windows Forms app.

Comment: Well blow me down!  I learnt something new today!  Thanks +1

Answer (score 0):

LongRunning is

> Specifies that a task will be a long-running, coarse-grained operation involving fewer, larger components than fine-grained systems. It provides a hint to the TaskScheduler that oversubscription may be warranted. Oversubscription lets you create more threads than the available number of hardware threads. It also provides a hint to the task scheduler that an additional thread might be required for the task so that it does not block the forward progress of other threads or work items on the local thread-pool queue.

I would recommend using [Quartz-Scheduler](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) for this type of scenario. It has more complex and comprehensive options for scheduling work over time.

```
// construct a scheduler factory
NameValueCollection props = new NameValueCollection
{
    { "quartz.serializer.type", "binary" }
};
StdSchedulerFactory factory = new StdSchedulerFactory(props);

// get a scheduler
IScheduler sched = await factory.GetScheduler();
await sched.Start();

// define the job and tie it to our HelloJob class
IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<HelloJob>()
    .WithIdentity("myJob", "group1")
    .Build();

// Trigger the job to run now, and then every 40 seconds
ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
    .WithIdentity("myTrigger", "group1")
    .StartNow()
    .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
        .WithIntervalInSeconds(40)
        .RepeatForever())
.Build();

await sched.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

The `HelloJob` must implement `IJob` interface to be treated as a job.

Comment: Not bad.  But the problem with libraries like _Quartz_ is that it follows old-style c++ patterns where you _made a class for each type of job_ and there was a method for the thread entry point.  Contemporary patterns like `Task` only require a method in _any_ class not to mention support for anonymous methods.   _Reactive Framework_ is perhaps another option if you want the equivalent to `WithIntervalInSeconds` etc

Comment: You are correct, but I like the c++ pattern because you can test more easily the jobs and the are more clear in code. Also, give you a clear definition of what is a "job" and what is a task.